# Как при загрузке файла в Storage Digital Ocean сделать этот файл Public?

Tags: python, digitalocean

Я загружаю код в Storage Digital Ocean и мне нужно, чтобы этот файл сразу стал доступным публично. По-умолчанию он приватный.

Загружаю так:

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        's3',
        region_name='fra1',
        endpoint_url='https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com',
        aws_access_key_id='',
        aws_secret_access_key='',
    )

    # # create new bucket
    # client.create_bucket(Bucket='your-bucket-name')

    # upload file
    with open(video, 'rb') as video:
        client.put_object(
            Bucket='your-bucket-name',
            Key='test.mp4',
            Body=video,
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо добавить вот этот параметр, при загрузке файла

```
ACL: "public-read",
```